# Checking if column is null Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have this column ('time_out') in a table of my database:

[image]

As you can see the `time_out` is `null`, and when I do this query:

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
                  ->where('attend_date', $date)->get(['time_out']);
```

I get this output:

> [{"time_out":null}]

But when I use it in an `if-else statement:`

```
if ($checkertimeout->isEmpty())
{
    echo "works";
}
else
{
    echo "wont work";
}
```

It display **won't work**.

Any help is appreciated, I'm new to Eloquent query :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, when you do this:

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->get(['time_out']); // <---
```

You are getting a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) of all the `time_out` fields of every `Attendance` models that match your criteria (the `where`s). This means, something like this:

> ```
> => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3323
>      all: [
>        App\Attendance {#3332
>          attend_date: "2019-10-06 22:01:29",
>        },
>        App\Attendance {#3340
>          attend_date: "2019-10-06 22:01:29",
>        },
>        App\Attendance {#314
>          attend_date: null,
>        },
>      ],
>    }
> ```

You can get more info in the [Eloquent section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models) of the documentation.

Now, if your query is designed to get only one record, you could use the `->first()` method instead of the `get()` one. This method will return the first `Attendance` object that matches your criteria.

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->first(); // <---
```

PS: If you only need to retrieve the `time_out` value, you could also add the `->select('attend_date')` to the query:

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ->select('time_out'); // <---
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->first(); // <---
```

With these clarifications, let's go to your question. If you want to check if a field is null.. you could just make use of the PHP function `is_null()`.

#### Using the collection

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->get(['time_out']);

if(is_null($checkertimeout->first()->time_out))
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Using a single object

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ->select('time_out'); // <---
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->first(); // <---

if(is_null($checkertimeout->time_out)) // <----
{
    // ...
}
```

---

### Side note

As a side note, if you want to avoid the null results for that value, you could add another contraint in your query:

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance
          ::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
          ->where('attend_date', $date)
          ->whereNotNull('time_out') // <-----
          ->get(['time_out']);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a very descriptive and helpful answer, I will surely note this one!!

Answer (score 3):

Hit it

```
$checkertimeout = Attendance::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
                ->where('attend_date', $date)->first();
```

## At Blade File If Else

```
{{ $checkertimeout->time_out !=null ? 'Wont Work' : 'work' }} // when this condition $checkertimeout->time_out !=null true its run after "?" when its false it's running after ":" term
```

For Controller You can also dd or echo like below :

```
echo $checkertimeout->time_out !=null ? 'Wont Work' : 'work'; // you can replace echo with return too
```

Answer (score 1):

First your query is getting all the records.

you should do like this in your query:

```
$checkerTimeOut = Attendance
            ::where([['emp_id', $request->emp_id], ['attend_date', $date]])
            ->first();
```

// This is to get a single record

then if you use `if else` statement you should also call the column you want to stablish.

```
if($checkerTimeOut->time_out->isEmpty()
{
  dd('not empty');
}
else
{
  dd('this record is empty');
}
```

you can also do like this:

```
if($checkerTimeOut->time_out)
{
  dd('not empty');
}
else
{
  dd('this record is empty');
}
```

or should be like this:

```
$checkerTimeOut->time_out
    ? 'not empty'
    : 'this record is empty';
```

Answer (score 0):

Event of the `time_out` is null, `$checkertimeout` variable is not empty. Because `$checkertimeout` is a collection. and it has one item in it.

As you can see like this.

```php
[
    {"time_out":null}
]
```

Since I don't know what you are trying to do, If you want the `Attendance` only where `time_out` is not null, You can do this.

```php
 $checkertimeout = Attendance::where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)
                    ->where('attend_date', $date)
                    ->whereNotNull('time_out')
                    ->get(['time_out']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $checkertimeout got a collection as

```
[
    {"time_out":null}
]
```

so its no longer empty and it returns

```
"wont work"
```